# How to specify the type of a member when defining a Struct?

Tags: ruby

```
Data = Struct.new(:lang_name, :number)
ss = Data.new("Ruby", 3.5)
```

I want `number` to be of type Float, and if the input is of type `String`, try to convert it to `Float` using `to_f`.

Comment: Version numbers are usually not floats, the current version of Ruby is, for example, `3.2.2`.

Comment: Since both `String` and `Float` have a `to_f` method, you could simply not care whether your input is of type string and always apply `to_f` to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
C = Struct.new(:lang_name, :number)
  #=> C
```

`C` is of course a class with getters and setters:

```
C.class
  #=> Class

C.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:number, :lang_name, :lang_name=, :number=]
```

`C` also has an `initialize` method:

```
C.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:initialize]
```

that it inherits from `Struct`:

```
C.superclass
  #=> Struct
```

```
Struct.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:initialize, :initialize_copy]
```

That method creates instance variables `@lang_name` and `@number`. We therefore can define a method `initialize` in `C` to invoke the keyword [super](https://apidock.com/ruby/Method/super_method) with arguments `lang_name` and `number` converted to a float. That will execute the original `initialize` with those arguments:

```
class C
  def initialize(lang_name, number)
    super(lang_name, number.to_f)
  end
end
​  #=> :initialize
```

Let's first create an instance of `C` by assigning `@number` a float:

```
c1 = C.new("Ruby", 3.5)
  #=> #<struct C lang_name="Ruby", number=3.5>
```

We can see from this return value the values assigned to the instance variables, but to confirm:

```
c1.lang_name
  #=> "Ruby"    
c1.number
  #=> 3.5
```

Now let's create a second instance of `C` by assigning `@number` a string:

```
c2 = C.new("Ruby", "3.5")
  #<struct C lang_name="Ruby", number=3.5>
```

We see that `"3.5"` has been converted to the float `3.5`, as desired. To confirm:

```
c2.lang_name
  #=> "Ruby"    
c2.number
  #=> 3.5
```

Note that  is a keyword and that we depend on the method [Float#to_f](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Float.html#method-i-to_f) as well as [String#to_f](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-to_f).

Comment: Wait, parameter-less `super` takes the *current* value of the argument variables, even if it's been changed? That's amazing!

Comment: @Silvio, I decided to change `initialize` to make it clearer and save a line of code. Readers: Silvio was commenting on the fact that initially the body of `initialize` was `number = number.to_i` followed by `super` with no arguments.

Comment: You can also set _number_ via `c1.number = "3.5"`, `c1[:number] = "3.5"` or `c1[1] = "3.5"`. Creating a custom class might be easier than patching all the Struct methods.